# Google Cloud Storage Bucket Backups/Restores

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone have backup/restore knowledge with Google Cloud Storage Buckets?

I have just created my first Project and first Bucket.  Now I'd like to test backing up and restore, but I am being told to look for a 'Data' menu item in the left hand navigation section, within the Google Developers Console.  There is no such 'Data' menu section at this time.

Has anyone used this technology before?  I have an application that uploads files into a bucket, and now I need a backup strategy.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear from your question but I assume you want to back up the datastore from your app engine project to a GCS bucket.

You can do this with the old app engine console.  On the left side there is a link Data->Datastore Admin.  After clicking this you will see an option to backup the datastore to a bucket.

The new app engine console likely has this functionality as well but I still use the old one because I like it better and it has faster response.

Comment: Hi Kekito,

Thank you for responding.  You'll have to forgive me as I don't have a high level understanding of Google Cloud services and all of its components, and their relation to one another.

What I'm looking for is a means to backup the file contents within Buckets.  I currently have an application (not cloud based) that uploads/downloads files into buckets.  Everything is working well, but now I need to find a backup strategy for the files within the buckets.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at 'gsutil'?  It does bucket to bucket copies and recursion.

Comment: I have briefly read other comments regarding gsutil, and its ability to copy contents from one bucket to another.  This certainly seems like a valid choice for backups.  However, given my scenario (non-cloud application uploaded to Google cloud) what would you choose for your backup solution?  I am trying my best to spark a conversation that potentially yields several solutions.  Perhaps solutions provided by Google, and perhaps solutions provided by third parties.